TV show where the protagonist is a teen who is extremely knowledgeable of history
I remember watching this from sometime between 2007-2012 but I can't remember if it was a new series at that time. I thought that this show aired on Disney Channel but it wasn't on any lists I researched.
Plot: Teen boy who has traveled all over the world comes to a university/high school in America, that has connections to a nearby museum.
Other Details

The main character was blonde and was friendly, but lacked street sense when it comes to social conventions (because he has never lived in one place)
Before he came to the US he was meditating with monks
He constantly gets in trouble with the authority (possibly the government)
He had some fighting skills
The genre is most likely Action/History
The plot reminds me of Kyle XY


It was Unnatural History broadcasted by Cartoon Network in 2010.

Plot: This series is centered on Henry Griffin, a teenager with exceptional skills acquired through years of globe-trotting with his anthropologist parents. But Henry faces his biggest challenge of all when he moves back to America to attend Smithson High School in Washington D.C., a place stranger than any he's ever lived before. Together with his cousin Jasper and Jasper's friend Maggie, he uses the skills that he learned around the globe to solve the postmodern mysteries of high school.


Don't forget to accept this when you can! Well done on finding your show!

@AndrewMartin thanks! It was a very lucky find
